# How to get my tsql query results set to be in the same order as the where statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am writing a T-SQL query and I am trying to get the results of the query to be in the same exact order as they are requested in the where statement. Below is an example of what I am trying to achieve.
Thanks

```
Select LoanNumber
From Table
Where LoanNumber in ('123456789', '987654321', '741852963')
```

Desired effect: In the results I want those same loannumbers in the same order as they are entered. what I am getting is sometimes it places the results in various order. I've tried the order by clause but its still producing not the desired effect.

Comment: If its just those three numbers you could try adding a column via a case statement. Something like Case when '123..' then 1 when '987...' then 2 ... as order. Then do an outer select statement on that one and order by that new column.

Comment: insert your values into a temp table or @table variable, in the order you want them to sort.  have an identity column on the temp table variable.  Inner join to this temp table, and order by the identity column

Answer (score 1):

Since the `order by` clause is the only way to ensure result set order, you could go with building the `order by` clause that matches your `where` clause, like this:

```
select *
from LoanTable
where LoanNumber in ('123456789', '987654321', '741852963')
order by case LoanNumber
when '123456789' then 1
when '987654321' then 2
when '741852963' then 3
...
else 9999 end
```

If you're building the `where` dynamically, this wouldn't be too bad though, as the logic for `order by` would match at every step.

Comment: Better answer from Linoff in duplicate

Comment: That answer is different, and interesting (constructing the order with the `VALUES` clause and tuples), but I wouldn't necessarily say better, at least not intrinsically so (that I can see).  It would have to be dynamically generated in either case, so I wouldn't think readability would be quite as important...but to each his own.

Comment: @SlimsGhost Gordon has answered other question with answers similar to yours. Your answer is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's no native SQL way to say ORDER BY "order of appearance in the WHERE clause".

You could do something like what SlimsGhost demonstrated or you could use a temp table like this:

```
-- your table
DECLARE @Table TABLE(LoanNumber bigint);
INSERT @Table VALUES ('987654321'),('741852963'),('123456789'),('1234'),('123456789');

-- a "filter table"
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (ordinal tinyint identity, LoanNumber bigint);
INSERT @tmp (LoanNumber) VALUES ('123456789'),('987654321'),('741852963');

-- Using the filter table
SELECT LoanNumber
FROM
(
  SELECT ordinal, t.LoanNumber
  FROM @Table t
  JOIN @tmp x ON t.LoanNumber = x.LoanNumber
  GROUP BY ordinal, t.LoanNumber
) ln
ORDER BY ordinal;
```